# Adjusting the scaling of gauge charts using C3.JS

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

I am trying to adjust the scaling of a C3 gauge chart so that the minimum value is 50, the maximum value is 100, and the value being passed in is 75. In my mental model, that should make the arc go from the left side halfway through the gauge (from 50-75). However, instead the arc shows up in the middle, and the value calculated is is 50? I assume the value is 50 because 75 is halfway between 50-100 but I have no idea how to make the arc appear correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/8o4mqjf4/

I think the arc should go all the way from the left to exactly the middle.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#gauge",
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data', 75.0]
        ],
        type: 'gauge',
    },
    gauge: {
        min: 50,
        max: 100
    },
    color: {

    }
});
```

Comment: Could you make a picture of your "mental model"? Just something very simple so that I understand what you are after.

(Try http://www.onemotion.com/flash/sketch-paint/ for example).

Answer (score 0):

Your mental model is correct. The gauge isn't displayed like you expect it to because it shows a ratio by default. Use the label and format options to display the value instead:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#gauge",
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data', 75.0]
        ],
        type: 'gauge',
    },
    gauge: {
        label: {
            format: function(value, ratio) {
                return value;
            }
        },
        min: 50,
        max: 100
    },
    color: {

    }
});
```